# How to make an alterable Xamarin.Form Xaml Page?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'd like to realize a Xaml Page in Xamarin.Form which can be modified by a user input. For example if the user click on a button, the app displays a Date Picker, and if the user click on another button the app removes the Date Picker and displays a Text entry at the exact same place.
I've tried to use the 'IsVisible' attribute but it doesn't work as I expected (the xaml object is still there but is just invisible, so I can't replace it).

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove a child.

Like this:

> 

`Children.Remove` or `Children.RemoveAt`

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.layout-1.children?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Didn't know about that, but it works . Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let your xaml page display like an alert , you could use the plugin [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) from nuget .

#### Usage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="MyProject.MyPopupPage">
    <!--You can set an animation in the xaml file or in the csharp code behind-->
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>

    <!--You can use any elements here which are extended from Xamarin.Forms.View-->
    <StackLayout 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
        <Label
            Text="Test"/>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

```
public partial class MyPopupPage : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
    {
        public MyPopupPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
        }

        // ### Methods for supporting animations in your popup page ###

        // Invoked before an animation appearing
        protected override void OnAppearingAnimationBegin()
        {
            base.OnAppearingAnimationBegin();
        }

        // Invoked after an animation appearing
        protected override void OnAppearingAnimationEnd()
        {
            base.OnAppearingAnimationEnd();
        }

        // Invoked before an animation disappearing
        protected override void OnDisappearingAnimationBegin()
        {
            base.OnDisappearingAnimationBegin();
        }

        // Invoked after an animation disappearing
        protected override void OnDisappearingAnimationEnd()
        {
            base.OnDisappearingAnimationEnd();
        }

        protected override Task OnAppearingAnimationBeginAsync()
        {
            return base.OnAppearingAnimationBeginAsync();
        }

        protected override Task OnAppearingAnimationEndAsync()
        {
            return base.OnAppearingAnimationEndAsync();
        }

        protected override Task OnDisappearingAnimationBeginAsync()
        {
            return base.OnDisappearingAnimationBeginAsync();
        }

        protected override Task OnDisappearingAnimationEndAsync()
        {
            return base.OnDisappearingAnimationEndAsync();
        }

        // ### Overrided methods which can prevent closing a popup page ###

        // Invoked when a hardware back button is pressed
        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            // Return true if you don't want to close this popup page when a back button is pressed
            return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
        }

        // Invoked when background is clicked
        protected override bool OnBackgroundClicked()
        {
            // Return false if you don't want to close this popup page when a background of the popup page is clicked
            return base.OnBackgroundClicked();
        }
    }
```

The plugin has default animations which you can use very simply . For more details you could check https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/PopupPage .

Comment: Thank you very much for your long and complete answer but as a begginer I think I'll do something simpler for my application. Thank you anyway for taking the time to answer me